# Paging's buggy with SQL proxy?

Tags: gridview, pagination, sencha-touch, web-sql

I'm using Mitchell Simoens's grid whose store is based on a SQL proxy. When adding the paging feature, it looks like the store is not getting correct infos from the proxy, in particular getTotalCount which returns the number of records corresponding to pageSize and not the number of records in database.

Any ideas about this issue ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. I modifed the selectRecords in the SQL proxy to get the total count of records from the database.

The code looks like this:

```
transaction.executeSql(sql, null, function (transaction, resultSet) {
        rows = resultSet.rows;
        count = rows.length;

        for (i = 0, ln = count; i < ln; i++) {
            data = rows.item(i);
            records.push({
                clientId: null,
                id: data[idProperty],
                data: data,
                node: data
            });
        }

        transaction.executeSql(sqlTotalRecords, null, function (tx, results) {
            var recordCount = results.rows.item(0).TotalCount;
            result.setSuccess(true);
            result.setTotal(recordCount);
            result.setCount(count);

            Ext.callback(callback, scope || me, [result]);
        });
    }, function (transaction, errors) {
        result.setSuccess(false);
        result.setTotal(0);
        result.setCount(0);

        console.log(errors);
        Ext.callback(callback, scope || me, [result]);
    });
```

where the sqlTotalRecords value is something like

'SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCount FROM Table'

Comment: How can I change the method behaviour without changing the library's source code ? Do I need to subclass the proxy ?